# QVariant output issue

Tags: python, string, pyqt5, qvariant

I am doing a test as I am getting this error in my actual application as well but if i can solve it on this test script then I should be able to solve it in my app.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

# Sample QVariant-like object containing a string
qvariant_like = QVariant("123.456")

# Convert the QVariant to a Python string using str()
string_value = str(qvariant_like)

# Print the string value
print(string_value)  # Output: "123.456"
```

issue I am faced with is that the output gives me the type <PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x03DF4BF0> instead of the string value "123.456".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

qvariant_like = QVariant("123.456")

# Use QVariant.value() to convert
string_value = str(qvariant_like.value())

print(string_value)  # Output: "123.456"
```